# Do AIR apps gain any performance benefits when a user updates to a new version?

Tags: air, flash

Do users gain any performance benefits when a they update their AIR or Flash Player installs?

Let's say a new version of AIR is twice as fast at `array.indexOf()`. Does my AIR app or Flash Player app get that performance benefit when a user updates?

FYI My app is published using AIR 3.6 and SWF is published with swf-version 19. When I run my AIR app and there is an AIR update it restarts after I install the latest version of AIR so I'm guessing I'm using the newest version of AIR although my app is using AIR 3.6 API.

Answer (score 1):

If there is optimization in newest version of Air or Flash player (I mean in virtual machine), your application or swf will get benefits of new versions. But if Adobe team changed the way SDK builds code (translates it to bytecode), then you need to rebuild your app to get performance update.

So my recommendation is to rebuild application as soon as you get new SDK and make sure that everything works as designed.